# how can I add certificate in DSS

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, pdfbox

I've done somehting like that.  is it correct?

I 've:

```
        PDDocumentCatalog catalog = template.getDocumentCatalog();
        COSDictionary catalogDictionary = catalog.getCOSDictionary();
        COSDictionary dssDictionary = new COSDictionary();
        COSArray certDSS = getCertificateCosArray(certChainList);
        dssDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Cert"), certDSS);
        catalogDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("DSS"), dssDictionary);

    and code to fill:

    public static COSArray getCertificateCosArray( List<X509Certificate> certChainList) {
    COSArray certDSS = new COSArray();

    for (X509Certificate x509Certificate : certChainList) {
        PDStream certificateStream = new PDStream(new COSStream(new RandomAccessBuffer()));
        appendRawCommands(certificateStream.createOutputStream(), x509Certificate.getEncoded());
        PDObjectStream pd = new PDObjectStream(certificateStream.getStream());
        certDSS.add(pd);
    }
    return certDSS;
}
```

i'think It's done. is it correct way? what do you think?

Comment: The PDF key for the certificates in the **DSS** dictionary is **Certs**, not **Cert**. The key **Cert** is used in a single signature's VRI dictionary.

Comment: write that comment, as an answer, and I'll checked as an answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already written as a comment:

> The PDF key for the certificates in the **DSS** dictionary is **Certs**, not **Cert**. The key **Cert** is used in a single signature's VRI dictionary.

Details can be found in Annex A.1 *Document Security Store* of [ETSI TS 102 778-4](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102700_102799/10277804/01.01.02_60/ts_10277804v010102p.pdf) (aka PAdES part 4). It will also be present in ISO 32000-2.